# Possible for users to have unique instances of the same document? (not downloaded copies)

Tags: google-sheets, google-shared-drive

My Google sheet consists of a locked list of items and a single cell that can be edited.  This cell acts as a search box to filter the list.

I want multiple users to be able to search at the same time.  I would prefer not to do the "[copy trick](https://shakeuplearning.com/blog/force-users-to-make-a-copy-of-a-google-doc/)" since that requires users to have a Google account.

Is there a way to do any of the following:

1. allow each viewer to access a unique instance of the document
2. boot user off after ***x*** minutes; allow one user at a time
3. *(any other ideas?)*

Comment: Welcome. Have you already read in https://support.google.com/docs or in this site about sheet and range protection in Google Sheets? Are you looking for built-in features only based solution or would you like to use Google Apps Script / Google Sheets API (the later is off-topic in this site)?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If the users are not going to modify the file you can share it for view only and many can open and browse the file without making modifications. You can protect the sheets you want untouched too in case the others have edit permissions on the folder.
I couldn't find a way, I have a file with drop down menues to select parameters and have the report show different values and still have to make a copy for each team so they can check their values in their files, otherwise when somebody changes a parameter it changes it for everyone